# MySql login from Java app

Tags: java, mysql

I am making a desktop java app and would like to retrieve information from a MySql database that I have stored on my web hosting (GoDaddy). For example I would like to have a login to check for correct login credentials. I would also like to be able to pass information to my users. Ie I can just update my database and then this change will be reflected in the app for all my users to see. I am struggling to find information about this. Would I set up a remote MySql database? The problem is that I need to manually enter the users IP addresses. What if they use a different computer or have a different IP? Any help or if you could point me to relevant reading would be much appreciated.

Comment: Create properties file to hold  your database values and read it from your application.

Comment: Probably it is wise not directly access the remote MySQL from a client-app, but add an API-Layer with a server-side program that communicates with your client and does DB-Stuff for the client.

Comment: you using JDBC connectivity? So that your db connection string would be like this (jdbc:mysql://<IP>:3306/<DB>);

Comment: Please read this page on [how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and show us what you've tried out already by editing your question and including a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 0):

The simple and more secure solution would be to put a web service in front of the database. That way, all of the database access issues from IP to credentials are not available to your users. User logins then are elevated to a higher level in MySQL in the form of a credential table or two, not actual MySQL users capable of running arbitrary queries.

If you are really new to Java, I would recommend [Grails](https://grails.org/) as the framework for your web service. It is in Groovy, not Java, but Groovy is like a hybrid of Java and Ruby so you should have a lower learning curve than most Java WS frameworks. It's also modeled on Ruby on Rails, so it's a really fast way to build something like this.

Comment: Thanks very much for the replies. I am very much a noob in every respect. Could you also use something like flask and python for this?